# <p-knob> : ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, angular-cli, primeng

```
<p-knob [(ngModel)]="value"></p-knob>
```

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

---

```
<p-knob [(ngModel)]="value" name="knob"></p-knob>
```

> core.js:6456 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'knob'

---

I take this code from primeng [link](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/knob).
I tried to search on the web. But, I didn't find any solution for this. I am using Angular cli version 12.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

p-knob does not have a `name` attribute.
Do you want to pass the name as a variable?

In that case use `@Input()`.
Also, you can't have a two way data binding with an ngModel on a component level. It should be inside the template of this specific component.

You can link a value to a parent component using @Input and then ngOnChanges to get the change in the parents if needed. Use @Ouput to bring data up to the parent.

In short, your component can't accept ngModel and name

Comment: p-knob is primeng component and I read there documentation they used is a same way. And I also try to pass value through the value attribute but it doesn't work.
Please tell if there is any other way. 
https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/knob

Comment: Looks like the types are missing, do they specify a way to add the types?

Comment: are you doing this: import {KnobModule} from 'primeng/knob';

Comment: yes, I am importing this in my app.module.ts file.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now, Its working. 
I just install @angular/animations  and then p-knob start working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry My Bad, I just need to install @angular/animations and restart the server.
Now, Its working fine.
@mikegross Thanks for helping.